# AngularJS process form on form click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to submit a form when user clicks on any part of the form, and then process it using AnglujarJS. Here's how I tried doing it:

```
<form ng-click="submit()" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtr">
      <input type="text" ng-model="my_val" name="my_val" value="0" style="display: none"/>
</form>

var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtr', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
            $scope.my_val; // This is undefined
        });
    };
});
```

The problem is that `$scope` does not have form values. If I replace `ng-click` with `ng-submit`, the values are present, but I don't want to submit form by clicking on a submit button.

Comment: You need to declare `$scope.my_val` outside of the submit function.

Comment: To publish the form instance into scope, you need to specify the name attribute. <form name="example"> and then you can use $scope.example.my_val

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare and set to 0 `$scope.my_val`outside of `submit` function and also ij Js code there are unnecessary closed brackets check that as well.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtr', function($scope) {
$scope.my_val="0";
  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.fromvalue.my_val
    console.log($scope.fromvalue.my_val.$viewValue);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="fromvalue" ng-click="submit()" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtr">
<input type="text" ng-model="my_val" name="my_val" value="0"/>
</form>
```